# filter dataframe 1 column with other dataframe column pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

i have dataframe1 that contains contracts and i have dataframe2 that contains workers now i want to filter dataframe1 with a column from dataframe2. i tried at first to filter dataframe1 with one string and it works, this is the code :

```
contract_con=dataframe1.filter(dataframe1.name_of_column.contains('Entretien des espaces naturels')
```

and this is the code i tried to make to filter the same dataframe1 with a column of an other dataframe2 that contains 10 lines:

```
contract_con=dataframe1.filter(dataframe1.name_of_column.contains(dataframe2.name_of_column))
contract_con.show()
```

any help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution to make a list from dataframe1 and use it to filter dataframe2
this is the code to make the list:

```
job_list=dataframe1.select("name_of_column").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
print(job_list)
```

and this is the code to filter it :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
contract_workers=dataframe2.filter(col("name_of_column_to_filter").isin(job_list))
contract_workers.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a different dataframe you cannot pass the column directly. You could use [`isin()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.isin.html) after *collecting* the `dataframe2.name_of_column` into a list. But the easiest way is just to do a join like this:

```py
contract_con = dataframe1.join(dataframe2, "name_of_column", "inner")
contract_con.show()
```